# How to map SQL_VARIANT in Entity Framework Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

In core 1.1 I used the TypeName = "sql_variant" attribute on the property and it worked.

```
[Column("tx_value", TypeName = "sql_variant")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I have migrated to core 2.1, started to return the error (The property 'EnterpriseDetails.Value' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'string' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'). How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks fine. The issue is that SQL_VARIANT does not map directly to a 'string' primitive type.  Since the data that can be populated in SQL_VARIANT is highly variable, you will need to use the `object` type.

```
[Column("tx_value", TypeName = "sql_variant")]
public object Value { get; set; }
```

[More information on SQL_VARIANT from MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the time spent. Solved my problem.